# Sending Parameters to Web Services

Tags: asp.net-mvc, web-services

Good Morning,

I'm building an ASP.NET MVC3 event ticketing site that relies on 4 separate web services from Razorgator, StubHub, TicketsNow and one other.  The site owner wants to limit the events for which tickets are sold.  Therefore, a search function is built into the site wherein the site's database returns events meeting search criteria.  The task now is to make the call to each of the 4 ticketing web services to retrieve ticket availability, seating and pricing.

Question:  How do I specify parameters such as the event ID in my web service call?  Is it best to grab the ticket agency's entire catalog, save it to a database table, and do the search from there? (assuming regular updates of ticket data)  Or, should I request the entire catalog of tickets and do the event ID matching after the request is made?

Thanks much for your suggestions.

Comment: Wouldn't we have to know how all 4 APIs work in order to answer this question?

Comment: The 4 APIs function similarly.  They provide ticket availability, pricing and seating options for a given event.  So, the MVC3 site has the events by event ID for which ticket information can be sold, and needs to call each service to retrieve data about a requested event.

Comment: All APIs work similarly.  I almost don't understand the question.  If you can say "give me the event data based on id = 030303" then what is the problem?  Speed, latency?

Comment: @jfar - Do I pass the event ID as a parameter to each of the web services?  Or, do I load the data from each web service API into my database and obtain the ticket info that way?

Comment: I don't know.  How up to date do you want the data to be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure how you think this, but:

1. Don't ever transfer large amount of data.
2. Perform critical (resource consuming tasks) as centralized as possible. For example, give as much work as possible to SQL Server and get from the database only the data you are interested in.
3. Keep the role of each webservice intact. Each one should do it's own job, don't mix business logic between them.
4. Remember, each call to webservice need XML serialization/deserialization = time (processor power) + space (memory).